# Twitter Search API returns null Object

Tags: c#, twitter-oauth, system.net, tweetinvi

I have been using the Tweetinvi library to search tweets(.NET 4.7.2) for my application. Till last week the application worked fine without issues. Recently I have noticed that the application would return an error for a few minutes and then go back to working as expected. I did some reading and found that this maybe due to the fact that Twitter now supports TLS 1.2, so before the Authentication method in my code I added the line below :

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | 
                                       SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 |
                                       SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

This has been suggested in a few articles. However, I still see the same pattern repeating. The application isn't consistent any more and the debug log says it returns a null object on search.

Is there any other reason or solution for this issue?

Comment: What browser settings are you using (content type)?  Older browsers may not work with Tls 1.2 or be intermittent.

Comment: It's actually a desktop application. No browsers involved

Comment: You are still using HTML and a browser is HTML.